# Using a Bluetooth speaker as output for JACK audio connection kit

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, jack

I want to know if it is possible, to use a Bluetooth Audio Device (mine is a AMP from SURE electronics) as a output for JACK.

Currently i am only aware of the pulseaudio-bluetooth module and the possibility to run pulseaudio in combination with jackd the other way round: pulseaudio as a client(called source/sink) for jackd.

PS: I guess i'll have more latency and other issues as well and it is maybe an edge-case etc... but i'd still like to do it.

Comment: Just checked in to find an possible answer, but instead its claimed as off-topic. I don't understand why. Is it out of scope to ask questions about the two packages jack and pulseaudio, which are part of many *nix-distributions?

Please help me understand, how to improve the question, where to ask it else or let me know, why it is a off-topic question.

Comment: I agree, and sent a flag to the mods. Keep in mind that most mods are volunteers, and aren't always in agreement about which questions are on-topic.

Comment: @jpaugh Reopened as I couldn't immediately spot why it was closed as "a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own".  It may be difficult to reproduce, but we don't have a comment from the original user that says the issue disappeared.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Package `pulseaudio-jack` supports PulseAudio to JACK connections

If PulseAudio is not normally used with ALSA connections, ALSA Devices can be set to 'Off'

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 off
```

repeat command and change `0` to `1`,`2` etc. if needed for more audio devices

Better solution is to remove pulseaudio modules detecting ALSA cards:

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
nano ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

find this section and add '#' at start of each line to look like this:

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
#.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
#load-module module-udev-detect
#.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
#load-module module-detect
#.endif
```

Save and exit nano (can use any other text editor)
Restart Pulseaudio or PC to reload new configuration

Using JACK with D-Bus will automatically load Pulseaudio Jack Sink and Pulseaudio JACK Source connections

If both JACK and PulseAudio are running, Connections can be added with:

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink
pactl load-module module-jack-source connect=0
```

The sound output of JACK can be played back via PulseAudio with:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=jack_in
```

if Pulseaudio is started after JACK, the commands minus the 'pactl' can be added to end of configuration file `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`

Comment: I have this setup running since a while, but i struggle to route sound from JACK to the bluetooth speaker. When i add the pulseaudio modules i have two sources and two sinks but they are connected to the internal microphone and the internal speakers.

Comment: edited command in last post to show option to block auto-connecting of microphone to Pulseaudio JACK Source

Comment: suggest you try using Patchage to see and organise connections in JACK. And Pulseaudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) to connect sound from JACK to Bluetooth Speaker

Comment: Apparently, [ALSA does support bluetooth](https://wiki.debian.org/Bluetooth/Alsa), with some help from bluez. And, I know it's possible to feed an ALSA device to Jack, somehow.

Comment: thanks, i did not know, alsa can do bluetooth. I will give it a try

Comment: @noreabu If you have any luck with it, please post an answer! I'm facing the same problem. :-)

Comment: @jpaugh I have not seen much about Bluetooth in ALSA, but it would be a better option than PulseAudio if it can be implemented